# What does ''Willing to'' mean?

Tags: meaning, grammar

What does ''willing to'' mean in english? If you can explain it, It'd be great.

> People are always **willing** to believe the worst about others.
>
> I'm pleased you were **willing** to meet with me," I said as we alighted from my stolen car.
>
> Worse, he had again assumed she was a **willing** participant.

Comment: You could look up "willing to" and "willing" in a dictionary, which may answer your question.  If not, let us know why not.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It means that you, something, someone else, etc. are ready, eager, or prepared to do something. So, for example, you would be willing to make dinner if you were ready, wanted, or were prepared to eat dinner. It can really be applied to many different circumstances. I would mainly use it in the sense of wanting to do something, however. For example, I am not willing to do my homework, or I am not willing to do the dishes or something along those lines. Hopefully I helped!

Comment: Why is this voted -1?